# in the Fourier inverse formula for a distribution function, the integral is Lebesgue-integrable?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

To keep things simple, let $X$ be a random variable, $F$ its distribution function, and $\phi$ its characteristic function. If $0$ is a continuity point of $F$, then 
$$
F(0)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\phi(t)-\phi(-t)}{t}dt
$$
Are there conditions on $X$ that ensure that this integral is Lebesgue-integrable? (i.e. we can put absolute values around the integrand and still have a finite value)

Comment: Theorem 8.3 in these notes https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/characteristic.pdf looks similar to your problem; perhaps that is of some use?

Comment: Thanks, but it is just a reformulation of what I've written. My question is wether the integrand is Lebesgue-integrable or not

Comment: Well, if $X$ is symmetric (i.e. $\mathbb P(X<0)=\mathbb P(X>0)$ then $\phi $ is even and the integrand is zero. But I suppose that is not very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not believe that necessary and sufficient conditions for the absolute convergence of this integral are currently known.

Your inversion formula is a special case of the Gil-Pelaez theorem, I found in this

[this paper](http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/FourierSeries1992.pdf)

which references [Gil-Pilazez's paper](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/38/3-4/481.full.pdf)

However, I an unable to find an analytical result, only papers regarding numerical approximations.